# HOWTO add aggregate .NET COM Interop to an ATL EXE Server?

Tags: c#, com-interop, atl, exe

I would like to know how one can add a .NET C# COM object (created using the COM Interop facility of .NET) to a Visual Studio 2008 ATL EXE Server. Basically, I am trying to create an out of process Automation server to hold my C# COM object to allow it to act as a Singleton server for many clients. I think all I need to do is add the proper entries to the ATL EXE Server's IDL file? Does this sound right? Would anybody also have any idea how to actually instantiate my C# COM object then? I am guessing I need to redefine its GUID otherwise it would just instantiate the C# one right away? Thanks for any help.

-David

For Example:
.

```
import "oaidl.idl";
import "ocidl.idl";

[
 uuid(A9F9E81F-D5FE-4718-8078-E8378CFB3D3C),
 version(1.0),
 helpstring("Libreria dei tipi SSOLoginDLLServer 1.0")
]
library SSOLoginDLLServerLib
{
 importlib("stdole2.tlb");
 import "SSOLoginDLL.tlb";   <-- Reference included to my C# project which creates the TLB
 [
  uuid(A8FD5BC5-3B8D-4828-B9CB-6496A7A6D9B9)
 ]
 coclass CSSOLogin
 {
  [default] interface ISSOLogin;
  [default, source] dispinterface ISSOLoginEvents;
 };
};
```

Comment: It sounds like you have three questions kind of jumbled up ... (1) how to create a COM server in ATL; (2) how to make that server single-instance and/or have instances share a singleton resource;  (3) from within that server (or resource) how to instantiate and use another COM object (which happens to be implemented in .NET).  Could you clarify which of these you are stuck on?

Comment: The other two I can verify/test once I have the answer to your #3 :), so I would say how do I let the ATL EXE COM Server provide to the outside world another already written COM object. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

So you have one COM object (your ATL server), which exists for the sole purpose of giving clients access to another COM object (the C# object).  It's important to note that you're not talking about giving clients access to the TYPE (i.e. they will instantiate their own instance of the C# object) but rather to the actual INSTANCE.

So your ATL server needs to define and implement an interface that provides the necessary access.  You could either just return the C# object:

```
MyInterface
{
    IUnkown GetThatComObject();
}
```

in which case the client will also need to know all the type definitions from the C# library, so that they can work with this object once they get it.

or you could wrap it, so that clients only need to know about your primary type library:

```
MyInterface
{
    bool TellThatComObjectFoo();
    int TellThatComObjectBar();
    // etc.
}
```

Either way, I think this is what you mean when you are asking '[would I] need to redefine its GUID' -- yes, the types (and their GUIDs) defined by your ATL server need to be independent distinct from the other classes they happen to use.

(BTW, sorry I'm not giving you correct IDL or anything here ... I haven't actually created a COM object since 1999.)